# Fancybox not working (opens in new tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fajlovi/style/default/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fajlovi/misc/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fajlovi/misc/custom.js"></script>
<script src="/fajlovi/misc/jquery.notify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

<a class="fancybox" href="/ajax/user/pmform/2"><img alt="ico" src="/fajlovi/images/ico/16x16/email.png" class="ico">Send a message</a>
```

When I click on 'a `href`' element, instead of opening it in popup with `fancybox`, it opens in a new tab. And yes, it has the `class="fancybox"` included. No errors in console. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see any error on the console ?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Check if your paths are correct. Paste them after your main site like `yourdomain.com/fajlovi/misc/jquery.fancybox.pack.js` to verify the plugin is loading

Answer (score 0):

`<a class="fancybox" href="/ajax/user/pmform/2 ?>">`

fix the href attribute value to the zoom image url when popup opens with respect to the thumbnail image mentioned in the image src,

Right now the href value does not point to the image url. Also the tag is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

The error was to call `fancybox()` in `(document).ready(function(){})`.
Used directly, it's working fine.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fajlovi/misc/custom.js"></script>
<script src="/fajlovi/misc/jquery.notify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("a.fancybox").fancybox();

   
</script>

<a class="fancybox" href="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"><img alt="ico" src="/fajlovi/images/ico/16x16/email.png" class="ico">Send a message</a>
```

Comment: no, that's not the issue, just me forgetting to remove the '?>' when posting this question, issue still persists.

Comment: When running my snippet, you don't see the fancybox ?

Comment: the snippet works, but on my website it's not working, and yes, i did remove $(document).ready(function() {}); on my website aswell.

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual code you use, or start back from this snippet, adapting it to your case.
Notice that an error in "custom.js" can break the fancybox. Try to remove it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120325/discussion-between-identity-and-technico).